# Unaligned address in vtable

Tags: c++, arm, c++17, vtable

I don't know if this is the right place to ask a question like this, so please redirect me if needed.

I am working on an embedded MCU (STM32L5) and am having trouble with some C++ code crashing with a hard fault.  After further investigation, I determined that the cause is a branch to an unaligned (i.e., no word aligned) memory address.  After more digging, I found that this is happening on a branch to a virtual method.  And, to the best of what I can determine, it looks like the address within the vtable itself is "invalid" (i.e., not word aligned).  Here are some images to illustrate what I am seeing.
[image: vtable from the map file and memory where the vtable is located]

[image: assembly instructions where the fault occurs]

While stepping through those three lines (0x080349ce to 0x080349d2) the register values are as follows:

- R2 = 0x20005484 -> Pointer address to my abstract object
- R3 = 0x805a398 -> Pointer to within the vtable of the class (see the highlighted entry in "memory details")
- R3 = 0x8032f15 -> The unaligned address read from the the vtable in memory (see the highlighted entry in "memory")

My question is, should I be blaming the compiler for doing something it shouldn't be, or could there be something wrong with my code that would cause this type of problem?  I am compiling the code using -Og optimizations.

**EDIT**

The actual object (which I am calling the virtual method of) resides in the stack within a lambda as follows:

```
[this, event, args...](){
    Event<ARGS...> e(event, args...);
    dispatch(&e);
}
```

Where `Event<>` is a templated class that inherits from my abstract base class `AbstractEvent` and which implements the virtual method `clone()`.

The dispatch() function takes a `const AbstractEvent*` and calls a few more methods before eventually reaching the assembly code above (which is the `defer` method below).  Thus, at the point where I attempt to call the virtual method, the object should still be on the stack.

```
bool defer(const AbstractEvent* e) {
    if ((e == nullptr) || (_deferQueue.full())) {
        return false;
    } else {
        AbstractEvent* clone = e->clone();
        _deferQueue.push(clone);

    return true;
}
```

And for reference, the implementation of AbstractEvent and Event<> are as follows:

```
class AbstractEvent {
public:
    AbstractEvent(int index) : _index(index) { }

    virtual ~AbstractEvent() = default;

    int event() const { return _index; }

    virtual AbstractEvent* clone() const = 0;

private:
    int _index;
};

template <typename... ARGS>
class Event : public AbstractEvent {
public:
    Event(int index, const ARGS&... args) :
        AbstractEvent(index),
        _values(args...)
    {

    }
    Event(const Event& other) = default;

    AbstractEvent* clone() const override { return new Event(*this); }

    template <unsigned int INDEX = 0>
    inline const auto& value() const {
        return std::get<INDEX>(_values);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<ARGS...> _values;
};
```

Comment: How are you accessing the object? Are you shure it is fully constructed or not being destroyed at the time you call the virtual function. Without any code it's basically impossible to answer.

Comment: @jo-art Unfortunately, I cannot post the complete code in a meaningful way.  However, the object resides in the stack.  An abstract pointer to it is passed through a few functions until it eventually reaches this point.

Comment: @jo-art See my edit for more details.

Comment: 1. does your hardware support both narrow and wide instructions (like Arm/Thumb)? This often uses the low bit of the address to distinguish modes. 2. vtables are normally RELRO - does your platform support this (or RO at all)? 3. if you inspect the rest of the vtable entries, do their addresses make sense? There are two possibilities of corruption (if any): a. the vtable pointer itself is corrupted, or b. the contents of the vtable are corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @11c for pointing our about "thumb" instructions.  It turns out that my problem is no actually where I think it is and is thus not a compiler issue.  What I believed to be an unaligned address was actually normal behavior for the processor.

For reference, see the following:

- https://www.embedded.com/introduction-to-arm-thumb/
- https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289866046.htm